# Pine Script: Percent price change in a period of bars

Tags: pine-script

I would like to check whether a certain percent change in price happened and use this information to trigger a buy in a pine script strategy. I was able to compare the current bar with the nth bar ago. However, I would like to change this to check if within a certain number of bars the change happend.

For example, if the period was 8, I do not only want to compare prices between the current bar and the bar 8 bars ago but would also like to have a comparison between the current and the 7th, 6th, 5th, 4th, 3rd and 2nd bar.

Thank you very much!

```
 //@version=4
strategy(title="Percentage", overlay=false, pyramiding=20, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.2)

bar = input(title="Bars", type=input.integer, defval=1)
change = (close - close[bar])/close[bar]*100
plot(series=change)

buychange = input(title="Buychange", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=-0.5)
buy=change<buychange
strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true, when=buy)
```

Comment: Did you get it or did you find any script?
Im interested on build a similar strategy that can trigger an alert Thanks!